# How to enforce managed code be executed under .net 2.0 in .net 4 process (SxS)

Tags: .net, side-by-side, sxs

In some articles people mention "explicit run sxs".
Is it actually possible?
I've read several articles concerning the topic:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx

but it's still not clear if it's possible to **enforce** a piece of managed code be executed under older .net version from .net 4 process.

So far it looks like the only COM components can require older .net so .net 4 clr will automatically start SxS execution.
Could someone shed light on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the compiler generated CLR host, no I don't think you can do this.

I believe you would have to [host the CLR yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) and explicitly specify which CLR you wanted to load when calling `CorBindToRuntimeEx`. So you want load one CLR by specifying v2, and another specifying v4.

Previously, you couldn't do this at all, it would crash spectacularly.

You can't really say, "Oh, I just want this method to run in the CLR v2". Your "piece of managed code" will be in a different AppDomain, so you will have to do some sort of communication between the two AppDomains, such as remoting.